# How to use jQuery Autocomplete with this webservice?

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

***UPDATED***
Sorry, I should have clarified this better! Im using a 2 stage webservice, the first call returns the full street address with a key that can then be used in turn to return the address parts. To do this I wanted to use the jQuery Autocomplete component, but im not sure how to do it.

**Heres the first webservice that returns the full address with a key that can then be used to make the follow up request for the address parts:**

```
jsonCallback({
"Address": [
    {
        "Moniker": "03OAUSAQXcBwEDAQAAAAAvuBHAAAAAADMxABQA",
        "FullAddress": "31KhanRoad,GURRANANGNSW2460"
    },
    {
        "Moniker": "0XOAUSAQXcBwEDAQAAAAAvuBHAAAAAADMzABQA",
        "FullAddress": "33KhanRoad,GURRANANGNSW2460"
    },
    {
        "Moniker": "0POAUSAQXcBwEDAQAAAAAvuBHAAAAAADM1ABQA",
        "FullAddress": "35KhanRoad,GURRANANGNSW2460"
    },
    {
        "Moniker": "0NOAUSAQXcBwEDAQAAAAAvuBbAAAAAAAAUAA--",
        "FullAddress": "43KhanRoad,GURRANANGNSW2460"
    }
]
```

})

**And [heres](http://www.website.com.au/WebApp.asp?action=parse&reqtype=Mcntab&resulttype=JSON&moniker=0HOAUSHgHcBwEDAQAAAAEnco4AAAAAADE5AGQA)es the follow up call that to return the JSON of the specific selection -  this is the info I need to ultimately save in the db**

**Resulting JSON Object:**

```
jsonCallback({"Result":"OK","Address":{"DPID":"68847810","Full Address":"20 Some Ct, TRUGANINA VIC 3029","Unit Number":"","Street Number":"19","Street Name":"Khan","Street Type":"Court","Street Type Suffix":"","Suburb":"TRUGANINA","State":"VIC","Postcode":"3029","Building Name":"","Building Name 2":""}});
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'leverage'?

Comment: sorry guys, been up all night finding it hard to make sense -  hopefully my update clarifies things

Comment: @charlietfl  getting there ... just not sure how to manage the follow up call [link](http://jsfiddle.net/mindfriction/NPZsU/)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out in the end

```
$( "#addressline" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://www.website.com.au/WebApp.asp?action=parse&reqtype=cnlist&ResultType=JSON&callback=?",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: { adddata: request.term },
                success: function( data ) {
                    //console.log(data.Address);
                    response( $.map( data.Address, function( item ) {
                        console.log(item);
                        return {
                            value: item["Moniker"],
                            label: item["Full Address"]
                        }
                    }));
                },
                error:function(){

                    alert('error');
                }

            });
        },
        minLength: 5,
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#addressline" ).val( ui.item.label );
            return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) { 
            //  show label in box, not value
            $( "#addressline" ).val( ui.item.label ); 
            $( "#addressline_moniker_hidden").val(ui.item.value);
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://www.website.com.au/WebApp.asp?action=parse&reqtype=Mcntab&resulttype=JSON&callback=?",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: { moniker: ui.item.value },
                success: function( data ) {

                    if(data.Address){
                        console.log(data.Address);

                        // set hidden fields with verified address
                        $('#dpid').val(data.Address.DPID);
                        if(data.Address.qaserror){
                            $('#qaserror').val(data.Address.qaserror);
                        }

                        $('#unitno').val(data.Address["Unit Number"]);
                        $('#streetno').val(data.Address["Street Number"]);
                        $('#streetname').val(data.Address["Street Name"]);
                        $('#streettype').val(data.Address["Street Type"]);
                        $('#suburb').val(data.Address.Suburb);
                        $('#state').val(data.Address.State);
                        $('#postcode').val(data.Address.Postcode);

                        // show verification msg
                        $( "#addrverified" ).text('Address VERIFIED').effect("pulsate", { times:2 }, 2000);


                    }
                },
                error:function(){

                    alert('error');
                }

            });

            console.log( ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
            return false;

        },
        change: function(event, ui) { 

        }

    });
```